# If $f\in C_c^\infty$, is $f''$ bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Let $C_c^\infty$ be the set of infinitely differentiable functions with compact support.

My question is: if $f\in C_c^\infty$, does it follow that $f''\in C_c^\infty$? Then $f''$ would be bounded because of the boundedness theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ vanishes outside a compact set $K$ so does $f''$. Hence $f''$ is a continuous function with compact support. This implies that $f''$ is bounded.

Comment: Why does $f''$ have to be on a compact set too?

Comment: $K^{c}$ is an open set. $f(x)=0$ for all $x$ in this open set implies that all derivatives if $f$ are zero on this open set. Also $f''$ is continuous, so it is bounded on the compact set $K$. This proves that $f''$ is bounded.